After updating to expo SDK 51 I got an error of cannot read propery 'style' of undefined
Previously, my project was running on Expo SDK 49. Today, I updated it to SDK 51. However, upon running the expo project with the command npx expo start, I encountered the following errors:
Android Bundled 11242ms D:\Projects\Booking\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js (1661 modules)
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes.

I'm attempting to run the app so I can proceed with my work, but I keep encountering these errors, and none of the solutions seem to be effective.

Have you rebuild your project after upgrading?

Have you being able to get any solution or work around?, I upgraded from sdk 50 to 51 andi have this error too. Please share any solution you were able to get so far

@sam I'm also getting this error. Did you manage to solve it?

I couldn't find a solution, so I simply downgraded my Expo to version 49 again by using the command expo upgrade 49.0.0.

I'm not sure how you upgrade but basically expo  suggest that when upgrading,upgrade one Sdk at the time . expo doc:"We recommend upgrading SDK versions incrementally, one at a time. Doing so will help you pinpoint breakages and issues that arise during the upgrade process."
https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

any solution to the above error so far ?

Currently upgrading from SDK49 to SDK51 requires a major change in how the app is bundling your code and displaying it.  Previously Expo used Webpack but now instead is using Expo Router. The traditional "expo/webpack-config.js" has been deprecated as of SDK51 so you no longer use "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js" in package.json and instead it needs to be "main": "expo-router/entry" as well as a whole lot of other changes.
You can read more about Expo Router here: https://docs.expo.dev/router/introduction/
Here is documentation on how to migrate: https://docs.expo.dev/router/migrate/from-expo-webpack
Note that this error ERROR in ./node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/uuid/uuid.web.js:9:8 Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto' is happening when running npx expo start in SDK51.
(more details here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26706#issuecomment-1911213867)
Therefore I do not suggest upgrading to SDK51 yet.  However it is good to note that the way Expo Router navigation works is vastly different from @react-navigation.  More details for that can be found in the above links.
